# Datalake Analytics Job deletion

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I noticed that Azure Datalake Analytic jobs are automatically deleted after a while. 
Is it possible to deactivate the deletion of jobs? 
What is the default life time of a job?

Haven't found anything about that in Microsoft`s documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the job related files(scripts, dlls, graphs) are expired and deleted automatically after 30 days. You can configure that in Azure Portal > your ADLA account > Properties > Job Submission Limits, by default it is 30 days.

[image]

Let us know if you have further questions/feedback, my email is yanacai @ microsoft.com.